# Override FacebookButton in Parse Library

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am trying to implement the [Parse platform login wizard in iOS](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X-9zk2ArATI&feature=plcp)

more info is [here](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#fbusers).

This is the code that we need to add to `ViewDidAppear`to have Parse Login Modal. (after set the proper Delegate for the interface:  `PFLogInViewControllerDelegate, PFSignUpViewControllerDelegate`):

```
PFLogInViewController *login = [[PFLogInViewController alloc] init];

login.fields = PFLogInFieldsUsernameAndPassword | PFLogInFieldsLogInButton | PFLogInFieldsFacebook | PFLogInFieldsSignUpButton | PFLogInFieldsPasswordForgotten;

login.signUpController = [[SignUpViewController alloc] init];
login.signUpController.delegate =self;
login.delegate = self;

[self presentModalViewController:login animated:YES];
[login release];
```

We can access to the buttons in this way:

```
login.logInView.facebookButton
```

I can do this using selector:

```
 [facebookBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonInfo:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

And add my own Action, but still the default action did work also. I do not want to have this default Action.

What I want is, override this button completely. Can You help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call removeTarget:action:forControlEvents: pass nil for the target, NULL for action, and use a control mask that sets all bits (UIControlEventAllEvents). Something like this:

```
[facebookBtn removeTarget:nil 
                   action:NULL 
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents];
```